# Form with Select Multiple Post to WebAPI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-web-api

I am using C# Web API to receive the post of a form that have a select multiple.

My model in the Web API method is something like:

```
{Model: { UserName: "Test", Groups: [ {Id:123}, {Id: 2}]}}
```

In other words, my model is a class with some fields, and also an array of a complex type.

WebAPI works correctly if the form data posted is:

```
UserName:Test
Groups[0][Id]:123
Groups[1][Id]:2
```

However, if I serialize the form with `$(this).serialize()` I get something like:

```
UserName:Test
Groups[][Id]:123
Groups[][Id]:2
```

Which WebAPI doesn't handle correctly.

This is defining the select as:

```
<select name="Groups[][Id]" >...</select>
```

I have tried other ways to define the select, but I can't accomplish it.

I was able to workaround it by building an object based on the form's elements and passing the object to the ajax instead of `$(this).serialize`, but it is an ugly hack.

Does WebAPI somehow supports receiving properties that are arrays in the model posted from a form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and it was resolved by using https://www.nuget.org/packages/ImranB.ModelBindingFix

More info: http://weblogs.asp.net/imranbaloch/archive/2012/12/08/fixing-model-the-binding-issue-of-asp-net-mvc-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx

Comment: Andrii, welcome to Stackoverflow! When possible always include code and explanation in your answers. If the link you posted will die one day then this answer will be useless.

Answer (score 0):

For submitting a multi-select form field to Web API, you can just use the array value that is generated by the form to submit to the Web API, and in the controller model that you accept, you can specify the C# property type as string[].

*Example:*

HTML:

```html
<form>
  <input id="regularTextInput" name="regularTextInput">
  <select multiple id="multiSelectField" name="multiSelectField">
  <option>Option 1</option>
  <option>Option 2</option>
  <option>Option 3</option>
 </select>
</form>
```

JS:

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "http://localhost:####/api/MyController/DoSomething",
  method: "POST",
  data: {
    singleVal: $('#regularTextInput').val(),
    selectedVals: $('#multiSelectField').val()
  },
  success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

C#:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "singleVal")]
    public string MyVal { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "selectedVals")]
    public string[] MyVals { get; set; }
}

public class MyController
{
    public JsonResult DoSomething([FromBody] MyModel model)
    {
        // You will have access to the form values here, including the strings selected from your multi-select field
    }
}
```